# Is there a way to delete output in Python IDLE

Tags: python, python-idle

I have a doubt here, I am using Python IDLE 3.8.5 [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)] with Windows 7 64-bit.

I want to create a countdown timer, but with this code :

```
for sec in range(10) :
    print(sec + 1)
```

the output is :
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Whereas what I want is :

```
1 #erases output and then prints 2 and so on
```

How do I solve this?

I have tried the following ways from the internet and stack overflow itself :

1.Ansi codes :- ('\033c'), ('\x1bc')

2.system('cls') and 'clear' (It shows the cmd for a split second and then quits)

3.sys.stdout.flush

4.subprocess call system('cls') and 'clear'

5.Ansi codes:-'\x1b[1A')

```
#delete last line
sys.stdout.write('\x1b[2K')
```

6.using ('\r') and ('\b')

Please help me, it will be a lot of use to me if you guys tell me the solution.

Comment: [That is not possible with IDLE's Python shell. Shell never throws away output.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819599/how-to-clear-the-screen-of-all-text-in-idle-shell)

Comment: Thanks Ill use another IDE or terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one writes a terminal application, 'NO'.  Currently, one must test this terminal behavior in a terminal window.

The IDLE Shell is a GUI application and does not, currently, try to imitate a terminal.  (That is why, for instance, one can write, submit, and recall multiline statements.)  There has been some discussion of making 'some' ANSI codes 'work' in some manner, but no agreement.

I would like to offer the option to run code in the system terminal, but this needs more experimentation.

If one writes a tkinter application, there is a Progressbar widget.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows try this,

```
import time
import os


for sec in range(10):
   os.system('CLS')
   print(sec+1)
   time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: added sleep for visualizing the output